# Stringify MutationObserver mutations

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I was putting together [a fiddle to help someone learn about mutation observers](https://jsfiddle.net/wg4ahtf6/) and noticed that when you try to stringify a MutationRecord object that it comes out empty while console logging the MutationRecord comes out as expected.

How can I stringify a MutationRecord ?

```
JSON.stringify(mutation)

"{}"
```

---

```
console.log(mutation)

[object MutationRecord] {
  addedNodes: [object NodeList] {
    0: [object Text] { ... },
    entries: function entries() { [native code] },
    forEach: function forEach() { [native code] },
    item: function item() { [native code] },
    keys: function keys() { [native code] },
    length: 1,
    values: function values() { [native code] }
  },
  attributeName: null,
  attributeNamespace: null,
  nextSibling: null,
  oldValue: null,
  previousSibling: null,
  removedNodes: [object NodeList] {
    0: [object Text] { ... },
    entries: function entries() { [native code] },
    forEach: function forEach() { [native code] },
    item: function item() { [native code] },
    keys: function keys() { [native code] },
    length: 1,
    values: function values() { [native code] }
  },
  target: [object HTMLParagraphElement] {
    accessKey: "",
    addEventListener: function addEventListener() { [native code] },
    after: function after() { [native code] },
    align: "",
    animate: function animate() { [native code] },
    append: function append() { [native code] },
    appendChild: function appendChild() { [native code] },
    ariaAtomic: null,
    ariaAutoComplete: null,
    ariaBusy: null,
    ariaChecked: null,
    ariaColCount: null,
    ariaColIndex: null,
    ariaColSpan: null,
    ariaCurrent: null,
    ariaDescription: null,
    ariaDisabled: null,
    ariaExpanded: null,
    ariaHasPopup: null,
    ariaHidden: null,
    ariaKeyShortcuts: null,
    ariaLabel: null,
    ariaLevel: null,
    ariaLive: null,
    ariaModal: null,
    ariaMultiLine: null,
    ariaMultiSelectable: null,
    ariaOrientation: null,
    ariaPlaceholder: null,
    ariaPosInSet: null,
    ariaPressed: null,
    ariaReadOnly: null,
    ariaRelevant: null,
    ariaRequired: null,
    ariaRoleDescription: null,
    ariaRowCount: null,
    ariaRowIndex: null,
    ariaRowSpan: null,
    ariaSelected: null,
    ariaSetSize: null,
    ariaSort: null,
    ariaValueMax: null,
    ariaValueMin: null,
    ariaValueNow: null,
    ariaValueText: null,
    assignedSlot: null,
    attachInternals: function attachInternals() { [native code] },
    attachShadow: function attachShadow() { [native code] },
    ATTRIBUTE_NODE: 2,
    attributes: [object NamedNodeMap] { ... },
    attributeStyleMap: [object StylePropertyMap] { ... },
    autocapitalize: "",
    autofocus: false,
    baseURI: "https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true",
    before: function before() { [native code] },
    blur: function blur() { [native code] },
    CDATA_SECTION_NODE: 4,
    childElementCount: 0,
    childNodes: [object NodeList] { ... },
    children: [object HTMLCollection] { ... },
    classList: [object DOMTokenList] { ... },
    className: "",
    click: function click() { [native code] },
    clientHeight: 18,
    clientLeft: 0,
    clientTop: 0,
    clientWidth: 824,
    cloneNode: function cloneNode() { [native code] },
    closest: function closest() { [native code] },
    COMMENT_NODE: 8,
    compareDocumentPosition: function compareDocumentPosition() { [native code] },
    computedStyleMap: function computedStyleMap() { [native code] },
    contains: function contains() { [native code] },
    contentEditable: "inherit",
    dataset: [object DOMStringMap] { ... },
    dir: "",
    dispatchEvent: function dispatchEvent() { [native code] },
    DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE: 11,
    DOCUMENT_NODE: 9,
    DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY: 16,
    DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS: 8,
    DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED: 1,
    DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING: 4,
    DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC: 32,
    DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING: 2,
    DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE: 10,
    draggable: false,
    ELEMENT_NODE: 1,
    elementTiming: "",
    enterKeyHint: "",
    ENTITY_NODE: 6,
    ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE: 5,
    firstChild: [circular object Text],
    firstElementChild: null,
    focus: function focus() { [native code] },
    getAnimations: function getAnimations() { [native code] },
    getAttribute: function getAttribute() { [native code] },
    getAttributeNames: function getAttributeNames() { [native code] },
    getAttributeNode: function getAttributeNode() { [native code] },
    getAttributeNodeNS: function getAttributeNodeNS() { [native code] },
    getAttributeNS: function getAttributeNS() { [native code] },
    getBoundingClientRect: function getBoundingClientRect() { [native code] },
    getClientRects: function getClientRects() { [native code] },
    getElementsByClassName: function getElementsByClassName() { [native code] },
    getElementsByTagName: function getElementsByTagName() { [native code] },
    getElementsByTagNameNS: function getElementsByTagNameNS() { [native code] },
    getRootNode: function getRootNode() { [native code] },
    hasAttribute: function hasAttribute() { [native code] },
    hasAttributeNS: function hasAttributeNS() { [native code] },
    hasAttributes: function hasAttributes() { [native code] },
    hasChildNodes: function hasChildNodes() { [native code] },
    hasPointerCapture: function hasPointerCapture() { [native code] },
    hidden: false,
    id: "someElement",
    innerHTML: "Random Value 29.915196465590597",
    innerText: "Random Value 29.915196465590597",
    inputMode: "",
    insertAdjacentElement: function insertAdjacentElement() { [native code] },
    insertAdjacentHTML: function insertAdjacentHTML() { [native code] },
    insertAdjacentText: function insertAdjacentText() { [native code] },
    insertBefore: function insertBefore() { [native code] },
    isConnected: true,
    isContentEditable: false,
    isDefaultNamespace: function isDefaultNamespace() { [native code] },
    isEqualNode: function isEqualNode() { [native code] },
    isSameNode: function isSameNode() { [native code] },
    lang: "",
    lastChild: [circular object Text],
    lastElementChild: null,
    localName: "p",
    lookupNamespaceURI: function lookupNamespaceURI() { [native code] },
    lookupPrefix: function lookupPrefix() { [native code] },
    matches: function matches() { [native code] },
    namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
    nextElementSibling: [object HTMLButtonElement] { ... },
    nextSibling: [object Text] { ... },
    nodeName: "P",
    nodeType: 1,
    nodeValue: null,
    nonce: "",
    normalize: function normalize() { [native code] },
    NOTATION_NODE: 12,
    offsetHeight: 18,
    offsetLeft: 8,
    offsetParent: [object HTMLBodyElement] { ... },
    offsetTop: 16,
    offsetWidth: 824,
    onabort: null,
    onanimationend: null,
    onanimationiteration: null,
    onanimationstart: null,
    onauxclick: null,
    onbeforecopy: null,
    onbeforecut: null,
    onbeforepaste: null,
    onbeforexrselect: null,
    onblur: null,
    oncancel: null,
    oncanplay: null,
    oncanplaythrough: null,
    onchange: null,
    onclick: null,
    onclose: null,
    oncontextmenu: null,
    oncopy: null,
    oncuechange: null,
    oncut: null,
    ondblclick: null,
    ondrag: null,
    ondragend: null,
    ondragenter: null,
    ondragleave: null,
    ondragover: null,
    ondragstart: null,
    ondrop: null,
    ondurationchange: null,
    onemptied: null,
    onended: null,
    onerror: null,
    onfocus: null,
    onformdata: null,
    onfullscreenchange: null,
    onfullscreenerror: null,
    ongotpointercapture: null,
    oninput: null,
    oninvalid: null,
    onkeydown: null,
    onkeypress: null,
    onkeyup: null,
    onload: null,
    onloadeddata: null,
    onloadedmetadata: null,
    onloadstart: null,
    onlostpointercapture: null,
    onmousedown: null,
    onmouseenter: null,
    onmouseleave: null,
    onmousemove: null,
    onmouseout: null,
    onmouseover: null,
    onmouseup: null,
    onmousewheel: null,
    onpaste: null,
    onpause: null,
    onplay: null,
    onplaying: null,
    onpointercancel: null,
    onpointerdown: null,
    onpointerenter: null,
    onpointerleave: null,
    onpointermove: null,
    onpointerout: null,
    onpointerover: null,
    onpointerrawupdate: null,
    onpointerup: null,
    onprogress: null,
    onratechange: null,
    onreset: null,
    onresize: null,
    onscroll: null,
    onsearch: null,
    onseeked: null,
    onseeking: null,
    onselect: null,
    onselectionchange: null,
    onselectstart: null,
    onstalled: null,
    onsubmit: null,
    onsuspend: null,
    ontimeupdate: null,
    ontoggle: null,
    ontransitioncancel: null,
    ontransitionend: null,
    ontransitionrun: null,
    ontransitionstart: null,
    onvolumechange: null,
    onwaiting: null,
    onwebkitanimationend: null,
    onwebkitanimationiteration: null,
    onwebkitanimationstart: null,
    onwebkitfullscreenchange: null,
    onwebkitfullscreenerror: null,
    onwebkittransitionend: null,
    onwheel: null,
    outerHTML: "&lt;p id=\&quot;someElement\&quot;&gt;Random Value 29.915196465590597&lt;/p&gt;",
    outerText: "Random Value 29.915196465590597",
    ownerDocument: [object HTMLDocument] { ... },
    parentElement: [circular object HTMLBodyElement] :
&lt;body style=&quot;&quot;&gt;
        &lt;p id=&quot;someElement&quot;&gt;Random Value 29.915196465590597&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;button id=&quot;theButton&quot;&gt;
      Update
    &lt;/button&gt;
    
        &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;//&lt;![CDATA[
    
    
    function callback(mutationList, observer) {
      mutationList.forEach( (mutation) =&gt; {
            console.log(mutation, JSON.stringify(mutation))
        switch(mutation.type) {
          case 'childList':
            /* One or more children have been added to and/or removed
               from the tree.
               (See mutation.addedNodes and mutation.removedNodes.) */
            break;
          case 'attributes':
            /* An attribute value changed on the element in
               mutation.target.
               The attribute name is in mutation.attributeName, and
               its previous value is in mutation.oldValue. */
            break;
        }
      });
    }
    
    const targetNode = document.querySelector(&quot;#someElement&quot;);
    const observerOptions = {
      childList: true,
      attributes: true,
    
      // Omit (or set to false) to observe only changes to the parent node
      subtree: true
    }
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
    observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
    
    document.querySelector('#theButton').onclick = function() {
        targetNode.innerText = 'Random Value ' + Math.random()*100;
    }
    
    
      //]]&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    
      &lt;script&gt;
        // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
        if (window.parent &amp;&amp; window.parent.parent){
          window.parent.parent.postMessage([&quot;resultsFrame&quot;, {
            height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
            slug: &quot;&quot;
          }], &quot;*&quot;)
        }
    
        // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
        window.name = &quot;result&quot;
      &lt;/script&gt;
    
        &lt;script&gt;
          let allLines = []
    
          window.addEventListener(&quot;message&quot;, (message) =&gt; {
            if (message.data.console){
              let insert = document.querySelector(&quot;#insert&quot;)
              allLines.push(message.data.console.payload)
              insert.innerHTML = allLines.join(&quot;;\r&quot;)
    
              let result = eval.call(null, message.data.console.payload)
              if (result !== undefined){
                console.log(result)
              }
            }
          })
        &lt;/script&gt;
    
    
    
    &lt;/body&gt;,
    parentNode: [circular object HTMLBodyElement] :
&lt;body style=&quot;&quot;&gt;
        &lt;p id=&quot;someElement&quot;&gt;Random Value 29.915196465590597&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;button id=&quot;theButton&quot;&gt;
      Update
    &lt;/button&gt;
    
        &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;//&lt;![CDATA[
    
    
    function callback(mutationList, observer) {
      mutationList.forEach( (mutation) =&gt; {
            console.log(mutation, JSON.stringify(mutation))
        switch(mutation.type) {
          case 'childList':
            /* One or more children have been added to and/or removed
               from the tree.
               (See mutation.addedNodes and mutation.removedNodes.) */
            break;
          case 'attributes':
            /* An attribute value changed on the element in
               mutation.target.
               The attribute name is in mutation.attributeName, and
               its previous value is in mutation.oldValue. */
            break;
        }
      });
    }
    
    const targetNode = document.querySelector(&quot;#someElement&quot;);
    const observerOptions = {
      childList: true,
      attributes: true,
    
      // Omit (or set to false) to observe only changes to the parent node
      subtree: true
    }
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
    observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
    
    document.querySelector('#theButton').onclick = function() {
        targetNode.innerText = 'Random Value ' + Math.random()*100;
    }
    
    
      //]]&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    
      &lt;script&gt;
        // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
        if (window.parent &amp;&amp; window.parent.parent){
          window.parent.parent.postMessage([&quot;resultsFrame&quot;, {
            height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
            slug: &quot;&quot;
          }], &quot;*&quot;)
        }
    
        // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
        window.name = &quot;result&quot;
      &lt;/script&gt;
    
        &lt;script&gt;
          let allLines = []
    
          window.addEventListener(&quot;message&quot;, (message) =&gt; {
            if (message.data.console){
              let insert = document.querySelector(&quot;#insert&quot;)
              allLines.push(message.data.console.payload)
              insert.innerHTML = allLines.join(&quot;;\r&quot;)
    
              let result = eval.call(null, message.data.console.payload)
              if (result !== undefined){
                console.log(result)
              }
            }
          })
        &lt;/script&gt;
    
    
    
    &lt;/body&gt;,
    part: [object DOMTokenList] { ... },
    prefix: null,
    prepend: function prepend() { [native code] },
    previousElementSibling: null,
    previousSibling: [object Text] { ... },
    PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE: 7,
    querySelector: function querySelector() { [native code] },
    querySelectorAll: function querySelectorAll() { [native code] },
    releasePointerCapture: function releasePointerCapture() { [native code] },
    remove: function remove() { [native code] },
    removeAttribute: function removeAttribute() { [native code] },
    removeAttributeNode: function removeAttributeNode() { [native code] },
    removeAttributeNS: function removeAttributeNS() { [native code] },
    removeChild: function removeChild() { [native code] },
    removeEventListener: function removeEventListener() { [native code] },
    replaceChild: function replaceChild() { [native code] },
    replaceChildren: function replaceChildren() { [native code] },
    replaceWith: function replaceWith() { [native code] },
    requestFullscreen: function requestFullscreen() { [native code] },
    requestPointerLock: function requestPointerLock() { [native code] },
    scroll: function scroll() { [native code] },
    scrollBy: function scrollBy() { [native code] },
    scrollHeight: 18,
    scrollIntoView: function scrollIntoView() { [native code] },
    scrollIntoViewIfNeeded: function scrollIntoViewIfNeeded() { [native code] },
    scrollLeft: 0,
    scrollTo: function scrollTo() { [native code] },
    scrollTop: 0,
    scrollWidth: 824,
    setAttribute: function setAttribute() { [native code] },
    setAttributeNode: function setAttributeNode() { [native code] },
    setAttributeNodeNS: function setAttributeNodeNS() { [native code] },
    setAttributeNS: function setAttributeNS() { [native code] },
    setPointerCapture: function setPointerCapture() { [native code] },
    shadowRoot: null,
    slot: "",
    spellcheck: true,
    style: [object CSSStyleDeclaration] { ... },
    tabIndex: -1,
    tagName: "P",
    TEXT_NODE: 3,
    textContent: "Random Value 29.915196465590597",
    title: "",
    toggleAttribute: function toggleAttribute() { [native code] },
    translate: true,
    webkitMatchesSelector: function webkitMatchesSelector() { [native code] },
    webkitRequestFullScreen: function webkitRequestFullScreen() { [native code] },
    webkitRequestFullscreen: function webkitRequestFullscreen() { [native code] }
  },
  type: "childList"
}
```

```js
function callback(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach( (mutation) => {
        console.log(mutation, JSON.stringify(mutation))
    switch(mutation.type) {
      case 'childList':
        /* One or more children have been added to and/or removed
           from the tree.
           (See mutation.addedNodes and mutation.removedNodes.) */
        break;
      case 'attributes':
        /* An attribute value changed on the element in
           mutation.target.
           The attribute name is in mutation.attributeName, and
           its previous value is in mutation.oldValue. */
        break;
    }
  });
}

const targetNode = document.querySelector("#someElement");
const observerOptions = {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,

  // Omit (or set to false) to observe only changes to the parent node
  subtree: true
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);

document.querySelector('#theButton').onclick = function() {
    targetNode.innerText = 'Random Value ' + Math.random()*100;
}
```

```html
<p id="someElement">
Some Value
</p>
<button id="theButton">
  Update
</button>
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @NGI I did not and I'm sure it could be a number of things from async work not being finished yet to the mutation object only responding to certain toString requests.
`¯\(°_o)/¯`